# SSL certificate for Website behind a closed sonicwall?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I'm trying to understand if I need a ssl cert for a website which I have on a hosted box which is only accessible from an allowed list setup on our sonicwall.

So I have a client and his IP is the only IP address with access through our sonicwall on port 80 to the web server.  All other IP's are blocked at the sonicwall. Its also the only IP setup within IIS in "IP address and domain restrictions". All other IP's and set to DENY. Do I need a SSL cert for the web site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restriction by IP address helps to restrict who can access the site but does not secure the data transfer by itself. This means that passive data sniffing is still possible.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Just on passive sniffing. Would the hacker need access to the client PC(malware) or host sonicwall to perform the sniffing or can this all be done from the web?

Comment: @raymantle: depending on the network setup is might be sufficient access to the network of the client, of the server or to any network in between (i.e. access to router etc). With BGP spoofing it might even be possible to reroute the traffic (depending on the location of client and server) for better sniffing.